# Read cell format from Google sheet using Python (API v4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets-api, gspread, pygsheets

I'm looking for a way to read a cell's formatting from a Google sheet in Python, specifically, its background colour.

Two popular packages I've found to be able to read a sheet are [gspread (fork)](https://github.com/robin900/gspread/tree/support-cell-formats) and [pygsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets). I tried both and they work well in reading my sheet data, however from what I can see neither supports reading cell formats, only setting them. This [open issue](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/issues/186) on pygsheets' GitHub page describes the kind of functionality I need.

Essentially, where each row is a record that has timestamp, username, comments etc., I want to find all the rows by a particular username *and* only those that don't have a red background, sort of like this:

```
if ("Username" in record.values()) and (matching_cells.background != red):
        # Do something
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use the Sheets REST API directly? Or with Google's client library?

Comment: @tehhowch I'm looking into it but I haven't been able to come to grips with the documentation as well as the other two -- is this possible with Google's client library? Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: `spreadsheets.get`, request the appropriate fields. Note that the Python API Explorer can be **extremely** helpful: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.get  (it has an interactive and explanatory `fields` selector!)

Comment: That looks very interesting, I’ll definitely check it out. Thank you @tehhowch!

Answer (score 6):

Using `google-api-python-client` to obtain your authorized `sheets` API client, you can request the spreadsheet data with the [`service.spreadsheets().get`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.html#get) method:

```
def get_sheet_colors(service, wbId: str, ranges: list):
    params = {'spreadsheetId': wbId,
              'ranges': ranges,
              'fields': 'sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveFormat/backgroundColor,formattedValue)),startColumn,startRow),properties(sheetId,title))'}
    return service.spreadsheets().get(**params).execute()

desiredA1NotationRanges = ['\'Some Arbitrary Sheet 1\'!A1:K', '\'Some Other Arbitary Sheet\'!B2:D4']
all_data = get_sheet_colors(get_authed_service_somehow(), mySpreadsheetId, desiredA1NotationRanges))
# all_data is a dict with keys determined by the fields in the request
# (i.e. "sheets") and the output of the API method used (aka consult your API reference)
```

The code below uses the API response from above and makes two arrays, one with background colors and one with the cell values, and ensures that row & column indices are portable by prefixing rows and columns to ensure the data starts from cell A1, even if you requested a range like "C3:J5". This is provided as an example for converting the REST resource into more familiar types, and is not intended to be useful in a generic sense.

```
dataset = []
default_bg = {'red': 1, 'green': 1, 'blue': 1}
# all_data['sheets'] is a list of sheet resources (per the API spec.)
for sheet in all_data['sheets']:
    # The sheet resource is a dict with keys determined by what we requested in fields
    # (i.e. properties (->sheetId, ->title), data)
    print('Sheet name is {title} with grid id {sheetId}'.format_map(sheet["properties"]))
    # each range in data will only contain startRow and/or startColumn if they are not 0
    # (i.e. if you grab A1:___, you won't have startRow or startColumn)
    for range in sheet['data']:
        rowData = range.get('rowData', [])
        if not rowData:
            continue
        offsets = {'row': range.get('startRow', 0),
                   'col': range.get('startColumn', 0)}
        rangeBGs = [default_bg] * offsets['row']
        rangeValues = [''] * offsets['row']
        for row in rowData:
            colData = row['values']
            newBGs = [default_bg] * offsets['col']
            newVals = [''] * offsets['col']
            for col in colData:
                try:
                    newBGs.append(col['effectiveFormat']['backgroundColor'])
                except KeyError:
                    newBGs.append(default_bg) # Shouldn't get called (all cells have a background)
                try:
                    newVals.append(col['formattedValue']) # Always a string if present.
                except KeyError:
                    newVals.append('') # Not all cells have a value.
            rangeBGs.append(newBGs)
            rangeValues.append(newVals)
        dataset.append({'sheetId': sheet['properties']['sheetId'],
                        'sheetName': sheet['properties']['title'],
                        'backgrounds': rangeBGs,
                        'values': rangeValues})
# dataset is now a list with elements that correspond to the requested ranges,
# and contain 0-base row and column indexed arrays of the backgrounds and values.
# One could add logic to pop elements from the ranges if the entire row has no values.
# Color in A1 of 1st range:
r1 = dataset[0]
print(f'Cell A1 color is {r1["backgrounds"][0][0]} and has value {r1["values"][0][0]}')
print(f'Cell D2 color is {r1["backgrounds"][3][1]} and has value {r1["values"][3][1]}')
```

References:

- [Python Sheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/index.html)
- [Google API Python Client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation)
- [Google's Python API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/)
- [The `spreadsheet` JSON resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#resource-spreadsheet)
- ["Fields" Reference](https://developers.google.com/tasks/performance?hl=en#fields-syntax) Use this syntax with the API description of the response resource / entity. (Google also has an interactive fields builder somewhere in its API Explorer documentation.)

Comment: Formulating the fields piece is the hardest...

Comment: Which of those ref-doc links, did you use to formulate the `fields`, anyway? I'm not finding it anywhere.

Comment: To give a partial-answer to my own question, by using this question [Retrieving Multiple Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64600172/78409), and doing "fields=sheets", I got back the entire set of values being used in the cell-range, and so could find the ones I wanted. It would still be nice to know where it is in the official docs, granted.

Comment: @JohnC https://developers.google.com/tasks/performance?hl=en#fields-syntax

Comment: Under "improving performance"? That was going to be my third guess... :) Anyway, thanks. Although it mainly has the syntax, it does mention that wildcards can be used, so presumably "fields=*" would have given me everything, similar to "fields=sheets".